# Read .xlsx as pandas dataframe from FTP without writting to disk

Tags: python, pandas, ftp, ftplib

I want to read .xlsx file as pandas dataframe from an FTP connection, However I want to do this on memory without writing the .xlsx to my local disk.

Here is my current code:

```
import ftplib
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

ftp = ftplib.FTP("host") 
ftp.login("ftp_111", "hs12121") 
ftp.dir()

listff = ftp.nlst()
flo = BytesIO()

for filename in listff:
    try:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, flo.write, 1024)
        flo.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_excel(flo)

    except Exception as e:
        print("An exception occurred: ", e)
```

> KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the archive"

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get the error on the second iteration, because you do not reset the `flo` before `ftp.retrbinary`. I suggest you move the `flo = BytesIO()` right before the `ftp.retrbinary` call:

```
flo = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, flo.write)
```

*(I've also removed the `[blocksize=]1024` – what is its point?)*